# MVC Default code to execute everytime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to set my menu's based on roles. I have made a model to check my roles and based on that i build my menu.

I have different controller and action like example:

```
/ProjectTest/Reports/Projects
/ProjectTest/Admin/Client
/ProjectTest/Admin/Resource
/ProjectTest/portfolio/Schedule
```

How do I make sure that when user types in any of the above url it hits my model which checks for the roles?

Comment: Create your own `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then decorate your actions with the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

If you create a class that inherits from `RoleProvider`, and just provide an actual implementation for `string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)` this will be enough.  Your implementation should check your model to find out what "Roles" the user is in and return this as a string array.

e.g

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    // if model says user is in Admin and ReportViewer roles
    return new[] {"Admin", "ReportViewer"};
    // else return other roles
    return new[] { "User" };
}
```

Then, any action, or controller that you want to restrict to users in a given role, you decorate with the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

e.g.

```
[Authorize("Admin")]
public class AdminController 
{
     ... etc...

public class ReportController {

    [Authorize("ReportViewer"]
    public ActionResult Client()
    {
    ...etc...
```

Comment: A) Why would he need a custom role provider?  The standard role provider works just fine.  He mentioned nothing that would require writing your own provider.  B) What does any of this have to do with creating his menu entries in his master page, which was the focus of his question?

Comment: That's not how I read his question. "How do I make sure that when user types in any of the above url it hits my model which checks for the roles?" - that seemed to me that he was asking about role based authorization.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create a shared layout page that all of your "menu-based" pages use. This shared page could be strongly typed towards your role model, which would allow you to check who the user is and what their permissions are prior to loading the content of the page.

Im not sure how your model handles roles but from there you could stuff something into view bag, generate some chump html, etc etc so that your page knows what menus to load.